# SSD for OS and Programs, Spanned Multiple HDD's for storage (Home Server)

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have set up a Home Server. The Server is used for several purposes, but most specifically as a home Media server and online cloud, with local Back up.
Recently lost 2 HDD's due to severe power surge and I am rebuilding.
Because of this I have an opportunity to add an SSD Drive (128G) and 2 new one new HDD.

**Set up:**

System:
 - MB, Processor, Ram necessary

HDD's:

- 2 - 2TB HDD
- 1 - 3TB HDD
- 1 - 128G SSD

  OS:
- Ubuntu 14.04

(Set up to run as an internet server / media interface / DVR / etc.

Software:

- Subsonic (Audio Server)
- Plex (Media Server)
- Kodi
- LAMP
- Joomla
- ownCloud (Or possibly Pydio)
- Piwigo (Image Archive)
- PhPBB 3 (Test build page only)

And others as needed in the future

Under my old build I was able to utilize GPT to make one large drive, since all drives were 7200 rpm, this worked like a champ for several years now.
Gratefully I also have a brilliant back up system.

Under this new build, with the SSD drive, I would like to have the Ubuntu 14.04 OS and Software installed on the SSD drive (For faster server boot up and faster initial software response), and storage of data on the HDD's.

I would like to have the HDD's viewed by the system as one large drive (ie, approximately 7TB), and not as 4 separate drives

I have some concerns with the /Home directory only being assigned to the HDD Partition, and not the WWW folder as well, as my online cloud service, for friends and family, stores archives to the Sub-directories in the WWW folder, and not the home directory (I think ???)

**Now to the questions:**

Can I simply add the SSD drive and the HDD drives into one single GPT partition and assume that the OS and software will install to the SSD drive (Which seems illogical), or what OS installation/partition process should I consider?

Would it even be worth the trouble to add the SSD drive?

I guess what I am asking, in as layman terms as possible, what would the best build solution be, and the process to get it there.

I am almost a complete Noob here, so I hope my question makes some sense

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ZFS, nothing else you do will compare to its performance. NOTHING. Its also perfect for what you are doing; as I am doing that very same thing and under quite a load.  zfsonlinux.org

Comment: Sure, install the ZFS kernel mods, and add them to the pool in whatever config you prefer raidz1/raidz2, and use the SSD for the l2arc.  You will be astonished the speeds you get

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS/ZPool  Here is an ubuntu Link, I will also be happy to show you some tips if you would like.

Comment: Your setup is almost identical to mine. ZFS is also a copy on write file system. So its fast and extremely safe. With raid z2 you can lose 2 drives. I would suggest reading up a bit; or playing with it (thats what I did)

Comment: Would appreciate links to additional documentation, implementation, and a better understanding of the "Raid" set up, and if this will work across multiple types and sizes of drives.....as mentioned in original post, I am using both SSD and HDD drives and of different capacities. So this i sgiving me a lot of red flags at the moment

Comment: Below is a link with all the resources you should need. http://zfsonlinux.org/... sorry I mean http://zfsonlinux.org/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

I would install the SSD mounted as root (/) and install the OS to that location using "Something else" option of the installer. You could use an LVM spanned set (see @Rinzwind answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266404/can-1-partition-span-multiple-physical-disks)) for /home and format the resulting volume with GPT. You could make a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641891/why-not-design-having-the-softlink-symlink-and-hardlink-in-the-same-link) to your WWW folder and put it wherever you want. Since your question indicates your previous build, I think you do yourself a disservice claiming to be "almost a complete noob" but if you get stuck, drop me a comment and I'll attempt to expand as necessary as time allows.